# How to read weight from a scale that reports weight continously =001.100 and so on?

Tags: java, serial-port

I am trying to read weight from a scale that reports weight continuously .i.e., it keeps sending `=000.000=001.100=001.100` and so on. I am able to read it using [this generic serial port reader](http://sourceforge.net/projects/javaserialportt).

But it don't know how to receive only the weight in double.

1. I don't want the `=` only `001.100` as a double.
2. the scale reports other weights `=000.999` too before settling down to a max value say `=001.100`.

How can I solve this?

```
case SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE:
byte[] readBuffer = new byte[20];
try {
// read data
int numBytes = inputStream.read(readBuffer);
inputStream.close();
String strWeight = new String(readBuffer, 0, numBytes, "UTF-8");
Weight=Double.parseDouble(strWeight);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. store input as a String
2. Use String arr [] = String.split ("=");
3. Process each element of the Array Double.parseDouble (arr[x]);